# How to compute symbol RVA in assembly?

Tags: assembly

I can't figure out how to compute an RVA of a symbol in assembly.
(RVA = Relative Virtual Address = offset from start of the executable image)

If I write the following,

```
rva:
    .long symbol

symbol:
    .long <whatever>
```

the value of 'rva' ends up being the actual virtual address of symbol, because assembler, of course, emits a fixup record for it.  If there were a symbol corresponding to the start of the image, I could write 'symbol - image_base', but as far as I can tell, there is none...

Comment: Which assembler and which target OS?

Comment: As far as I know the name "RVA" is only used in Windows.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to create a .rsrc section in Windows executable in assembly, rather than via windres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a relocation type IMAGE_REL_I386_DIR32NB in object files that would allow such an expression.

However in the GNU toolchain the tools using these relocation types (windres and dlltool) directly write out object files and not assembler files.

Therefore I think (but I'm not sure) that there is no possibility to write such an expression in assembler (neither GNU nor Microsoft toolchains).

However there are two possibilities to work around this:

1) A modified a linker script that defines special symbols (e.g. a symbol "RVA_of_myVariable")

2) Write all symbols of this type - and ONLY such symbols - to a separate assembler file and change all relocations of type 6 in the resulting object file to relocation type 7 (for 32-bit files; type 1/2 to type 3 for 64-bit files). The COFF object file format can easily be parsed so writing a C program doing these changes should be quite simple.

Comment: Thanks, for the info.  Too bad this can't be done, I was hoping to avoid adding extra steps to the build precess just to embed executable manifest.